# How to save and view LogCat errors without eclipse? aLogCat?

Tags: android, logcat

I'm developing an app and I'm stuck with a weird error. I can't reproduce it always in my phone (galaxy nexus with 4.2)... It happens sometimes and absolutely never I've achieved to do it when I'm trying the app in eclipse (where I can see easily Logcat through console view)
The only message I've received it's a sad dialog telling me that my app has been stopped.

So I've searched for solutions and people says to install some app like [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) to achieve this. I've coded some "Log.d()" in my app but I can't see it anywhere.

So, here's the question... How Can I get more info from my app problems? Someone has used aLogcat or any other log reader? Why my logs are viewed in eclipse Logcat console but not in my phone (where I can only see GC_CONCURRENT and something like D/dalvikm...)

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English :)

**UPDATE** I'm using my phone to test my app and adb emulator too, but with emulator I've never have any crash. Actually I can't force this crashes because I'm having it randomly and alwalys with my phone. I've tryied to debug my app through my phone but I'm not been able to  connect correctly. If anyone could help I'll preciate too. I've got a galaxy nexus.

Comment: Did you run it in debug mode from the phone (with logcat)? Not clear if you meant emulator or phone when you said "trying in eclipse".

Comment: I test my app with adb emulator (this is my "trying in eclipse") and installing it in my galaxy nexus... I'm going to update my first comment.

Comment: You can be connected to eclipse while running it from the phone. This should allow you to get a log from one of those rare crashes you get on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to answer this question...

It sounds like you are using your phone (not emulator) to run your app and you are seeing inconsistent crashes, correct? Using something like Bugsense (http://www.bugsense.com/) may be of value to you. Many services like this one sends crash reports to you when your app has crashed so if you are using your own personal phone to do the testing, this may be a good idea since you may or may not be near a computer when a crash occurs.